# Undefined method to_model for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my User Controller

```
def nearby
  @nearby = Trip.near("los angeles, ca", 50)
end
```

In my User model:

```
geocoded_by :location
after_validation :geocode
```

In views/users/nearby.haml

```
= @nearby.to_json
```

I'm getting the error at this line:

```
Undefined method to_model for ActiveRecord::Relation
```

This is my routes:

```
resources :users, :path => '', only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'nearby'      
  end 
end
```

Can someone help me narrow in on what the issue could be?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method [`to_model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_model) can only be called on a single AR instance.

I think, you should call `to_json` on a single record as well, not on a collection